# jQuery datepicker set format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, format

How to set format to this `DD, d MM, yy`

I have try this and this is not working...

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "showAnim", "slideDown", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy" );
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker("option", "showAnim", "slideDown", "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy" );
```

Comment: `d` what is this in the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the options individually if you're doing it after initialisation:

```
$("#datepicker")
    .datepicker("option", "showAnim", "slideDown")
    .datepicker('option', "dateFormat", "DD, d MM, yy");
```

Alternatively, you can set the options on initialisation in one go:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    showAnim: 'slideDown',
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes don't look like they're formatted properly. Shouldn't they be something like this?

```
datepicker({"showAnim": "slideDown","dateFormat": "DD, d MM, yy"});
```